# Computing the minimal polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Im trying to compute the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ of $(1+{3}^{1/5})(5^{1/4})$, I tried get ride of the roots, but i got to deadpoints.

Comment: I think it's gonna be of degree 20 so it's not that easy to compute .

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\sqrt[4]{5}(1+\sqrt[5]{3})$. Then we obtain
$$
x^{20} - 25x^{16} - 10250 x^{12} - 357500 x^8 + 1090625 x^4 - 800000,
$$
see [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280251/computation-of-a-minimal-polynomial).